# I am seeing the 'questions not well-received' warning when I have no questions at all

Tags: feature-request, support, post-ban, warning

At https://superuser.com/questions/ask I see this message:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and
>   you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a
>   good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

But (at the time of writing) I have no history of asking any questions at all.
https://superuser.com/users/35488/myster?tab=questions
I have one well received answer, and one un-voted answer.

It's possible that long ago I had some deleted questions, I don't recall, but I can't see them in the recently deleted list. https://superuser.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/35488/

Could this be a bug? or just something to do with the warning algorithm I don't understand. Or have my bad questions been deleted? if so how would I see these? (so I can see what not to do)

**Edit**
In light of the very old deleted questions being the reason for the warning, May I suggest these should somehow be visible on the my questions page even if only to say "you have 2 deleted questions"

Comment: You have two questions, but they were both deleted in 2012 and 2014.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not a bug. You've asked some questions long time ago. As [@animuson points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270096/i-am-seeing-the-questions-not-well-received-warning-when-i-have-no-questions-a/270097#comment875197_270096), these are years old already. They probably got deleted after endless downvotes, hence you get that message.

You can't see them in your *recently deleted questions* list since they are... not deleted *recently*.

It is still important to read the help center carefully and check three times your question is up to standards.

Comment: The date of deletion isn't really relevant; rather, they weren't *asked* recently. (A question asked 61 days ago will become invisible as soon as it's deleted.)